# Refresh a contact's iMessage status

Tags: ios, contacts, messages

I've explained one of my contacts how to set his phone number as a recipient for iMessage.

However, his name still appears as Text Message and not iMessage.

How often does iOS check if a number is an iMessage number? Is there a way to force-refresh?

I've restarted my phone - didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It happens immediately. There is a chance that your friend hasn’t configured iMessage properly.

Tell him to turn off iMessage, and turn it back on.

Comment: It worked after like an hour...

Comment: It rarely happens unless the cellular network or data connection is unstable, or maybe slow sending the activation request. Nevertheless, the process depends not only Apple, but also the cellular network provider.